# UIButton not working on view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have two `UIButton`'s located on my view controller and on each button I have programatically added a `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method with each button. However, when I build and run the project I tap each button but nothing happens (see screenshot). I have tried numerous ways of trying to figure out the problem, one of them by adding a `print` to see if anything appears in the `debug` box, but nothing!

It might be worth mentioning, on this View Controller I have a continuous video.

Here is my current code:

```
    @IBAction func CreateAccount(sender: AnyObject) {

    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("signup") as! SignUpNavController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("Clicked!")
}
```

Here is what happens when I build and run the project:

[image]

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: what are you using for the video view? are you using MPMoviePlayerController? is the video inside of the webView?

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin a webView with the controls disabled. The video is on repeat as it is on a splash view controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go back to you interface builder (storyboard or xib). Right click the view controller and double check that the IBAction is connected correctly. If so then put a break point in viewDidLoad to make sure the IBOutlets for the buttons are not nil.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have checked that the buttons are connected correctly and also added a breakpoint in the viewDidLoad, but I get the same problem.

Comment: Try deleting the connections and dragging them over again. Also (not important) starting a method name with a capital letter is unorthodox. I am under the impression it's only proper to start a class name with a capital letter. When you press the button does the button animation happen?

Comment: I will have a go at it. I don't usually start a method with a capital letter, must have been a typo error

Comment: If it doesn't do the animation then there is a problem with the buttons frame or something of that sort. Maybe another view is eating the tap event.

Comment: Just had a go at your suggestion and it has unfortunately not solved it. I have also deleted the button and added a new button and that has not solved it either.

Comment: You can confirm that the button animation is happening each time you hit the button and still the IBAction is not being called?

Comment: No. The button does not animate or highlight when I tap it

Comment: Then we're getting closer to the problem. The button isn't receiving the tap event for some reason. Load up the page on the simulator or device. Then go to Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy. You can spin this view around to see every element, its size, and whats in front of it and behind it. Right click the button and print the description to see its frame. Do this to make sure it has its expected frame and nothing is in front of it.

Comment: I have added an 'UPDATE' section on my question for you to have a look at

Comment: The only think I can think of is making sure userInteractionEnabled is true on the parents. Something is intercepting the tap commands.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your help. I have decided to change the video to a view as a .gif instead, and when I add buttons to the view controller it now works. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to add this button programmatically to your AVPlayerView? like [player addSubview:yourButton]; ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value of zPosition of your button. It happened to me on multiple occasions that my button was not working and in the end i found out that it was because of some other view.

Try -

```
button.layer.zPosition = 3
```

// 3 is just a random value. If you haven't tweaked with the layers, I think 2 also should work. Lemme know if this was helpful :-)

Comment: Thanks ever so much for your help!  Your solution sadly didn't solve the problem, however, I decided to add a button programmatically to my AVPlayerView. Thanks